# How to read a file with multiple delimiters within a single line

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to read a file which has multiple delimiters per line.
Below is the data

```
2,22:11
3,33:11
4,44:11
5,55:11
6,66:11
7,77:11
8,88:11
9,99:11
10,00:11
11,011:11
12,022:11
13,033:11
14,044:11
15,055:11
16,066:11
17,077:11
18,088:11
19,099:11
```

And the code is below

Here, I am trying to read the line first with comma as delimiter to get line and then the colon.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string line;
  std::string token;
  std::ifstream infile;

  infile.open("./data.txt");
  while (std::getline(infile, line,',')) {
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
    while(getline(infile, token, ':'))
    {
      std::cout << " : " << token;
    }
  }
}
```

But there is an issue with the code as it is skipping the first line.
Also , if i comment the second while loop,only the first line is getting printed, and below is the output

Ian unable to figure out where exactly the code has gone wrong

Output

```
2
 : 22 : 11
3,33 : 11
4,44 : 11
5,55 : 11
6,66 : 11
7,77 : 11
8,88 : 11
9,99 : 11
10,00 : 11
11,011 : 11
12,022 : 11
13,033 : 11
14,044 : 11
15,055 : 11
16,066 : 11
17,077 : 11
18,088 : 11
19,099 : 11
```

Comment: I have updated my explanation with a solution. I think it would be a good fit. Take time to dive deep in the solution. Twist it as much as possible to wrap your head around.

Comment: Debugger is your best friend

Answer (score 2):

Why two `while` ?

Your problem is that you repeat the second while forever. The first `while` is executed only to get the first `2`, the second while is executed to the end of the file.

You can do all with a single `while`; something like

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
 std::string line;
 std::string token;
 std::string num;
 ifstream infile;
 infile.open("a.txt");
  while (   getline(infile, line,',')
         && getline(infile, token, ':')
         && getline(infile, num) ) 
    cout << line << ',' << token << ':' << num << endl;
}
```

Comment: Will  the variable named  token have the substring after the first while is processed ex : 22:11,  will it delete the string till comma  .Would you please explain?

Comment: It's likely that the `:` separated are a variable length list. That would explain the double-while. The real problem is the newline.

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from the fact you are using `std::getline` twice.

At the beginning you enter the first loop. The first call to `std::getline` returns want you expect : the first line **until** the `,` delimiter.

Then you enter the second `std::getline`, in a nested loop, to get the rest of the line. But the thing is, you never leave the second loop until the end of the file. So, you read **all the file** splitting by `:` delimiter.

When the second `std:getline` ends up to the end of the file, it leaves the nested loop.

Because you already read all the file, nothing's left to be read and the first loop directly exits.

Here is some debug to help you understand the context :

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string line;
  std::string token;
  std::ifstream infile;

  infile.open("./data.txt");
  while (std::getline(infile, line, ',')) {
    std::cout << "First loop : " << line << std::endl;
    while(getline(infile, token, ':'))
    {
      std::cout << "Inner loop : " << token << std::endl;
    }
  }
}
```

The first lines to be printed are :

```
First loop : 2
Inner loop : 22
Inner loop : 11
3,33
Inner loop : 11
4,44
```

You can clearly see it doesn't exit the second loop until the end.

I would advise to read the entire line, with no care of delimiters, and **then** split the string into token using a tailor made function. It would be easy and very clean.

**Solution :**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct line_content {
  std::string line_number;
  std::string token;
  std::string value;
};

struct line_content tokenize_line(const std::string& line)
{
  line_content l;

  auto comma_pos = line.find(',');
  l.line_number = line.substr(0, comma_pos);

  auto point_pos = line.find(':');
  l.token = line.substr(comma_pos + 1, point_pos - comma_pos);

  l.value = line.substr(point_pos + 1);

  return l;
}

void print_tokens(const std::list<line_content>& tokens)
{
  for (const auto& line: tokens) {
    std::cout << "Line number : " << line.line_number << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Token : " << line.token << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Value : " << line.value << std::endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  std::string line;
  std::ifstream infile;

  std::list<line_content> tokens;

  infile.open("./data.txt");
  while (std::getline(infile, line)) {
    tokens.push_back(tokenize_line(line));
  }

  print_tokens(tokens);

  return 0;
}
```

I think you should be able to do what you what.

Compiled as follow : `g++ -Wall -Wextra --std=c++1y <your c++ file>`

Comment: Hi Thanks for the code , Tried running this and i liked the idea of maintaining a string and then work on it , but is nt there a simple mechanism that the library provides.

Comment: _is'nt there a simple mechanism that the library provide ?_ For what exactly ? String splitting ? Or for the struct stuff ?

Comment: This code works if all the lines have the sepcified delimiters(1,2:3) , if any delimiter is missing (say 1,2) in  a line, then it is considering the whole line as value again.
Well, the entries in the file may or may not have all the delimiters , how would this solution work . Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split a string on multiple delimiters, without having to worry about the order of the delimiters, you can use `std::string::find_first_of()`

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <streambuf>
#include <string>

int
main()
{
        std::ifstream f("./data.txt");
        std::string fstring = std::string(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(f),
                                          std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
        std::size_t next, pos = 0;
        while((next = fstring.find_first_of(",:\n", pos)) != std::string::npos)
        {
                std::cout.write(&fstring[pos], ++next - pos);
                pos = next;
        }

        std::cout << &fstring[pos] << '\n';

        return 0;
}
```